# Saving to particular directory from Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, working-directory

I am running python code where I want to write some output to a particular folder (which different from the location where I execute the script).

Therefore I was planning to change the path of Python to this particular folder using the os module:

```
os.chdir("myLocation.../Folder")
```

However, the script still writes to the folder where I executed the script, and when I invoke the command

```
os.curdir
```

it returns ".".

I am a little bit lost here and would appreciate any hint.

Comment: `os.curdir` will not give cwd. What does `os.getcwd` tell you?

Comment: Okay, with this os.getcwd I will be able to debug my code, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.chdir` should do the correct thing. Here is some code used for testing on python REPL, assuming you have a `./test` dir in working dir.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('test')
>>> f = open('testfile', 'w')
>>> print>>f, 'hello world'
>>> f.close()
```

`test/testfile` is now present with the right contents.

Comment: Thanks, when I run it manually in the python shell at home it seems to work. So there must be some other issue in my script. the os.curdir command confused me a little bit. How do I get os.curdir to print the absolute path instead of "."? Also, I find this print>>f expression very handy, do you know the python 3 equivalent of it? EDIT: okay, I just saw the hint to use os.getcwd instead of os.curdir

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9236236/567555) seems to answer your question about python 3.