# python `f.write()` and `print >>` differ by one empty line

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, fwrite

I have code with the following statement which works fine

```
with open(fname, 'w') as f:
    print >> f, result
```

Here `result` is not a string, but some custom object.

Now I changed it to

```
with open(fname, 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(result))
```

It basically works, but there is an extra empty line at the end. Is there a clean way to get rid of it, or even not generate it in the first place?

Comment: print appends by default a newline at the end, while f.write() doesn't

Comment: I've posted an answer but now I'm dubious. `print` adds a newline in the end, `write` doesn't. You are saying that it's the other way round. I'm puzzled. Did you invert the snippets?

Comment: Here `result` is some custom object. Your answer indeed gets rid of the empty line at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able, in python 2, to use `print`, without a newline and with file redirection, you could import python 3 `print` function using `__futures__`, and enjoy the new parameters of this function:

```
from __future__ import print_function

with open("U:/foo.txt","w") as f:
    print("a",end="",file=f)
```

references:

- [Python 3 operator >> to print to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236198/python-3-operator-to-print-to-file)
- [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)